# How to unlock columns in Excel using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

Good Morning

I have a program in VB.Net that exports a file from Datagridview into Excel file
and it looks like this.

[image]

My goal here is how can I lock some columns? based on the Image above? Lock all columns except the column that has a color yellow? I mean all the columns except the yellow are uneditable.

Here is my code in exporting excel

```
  Try
            If DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Nothing to Export")
            Else
                Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
                Dim ExcelSheet As Object
                Dim i As Integer
                Dim J As Integer
                Dim rowIndex As Integer = 1
                Dim total As Double = 0
                Dim indexTotal As Integer

                ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
                ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
                ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)
                With ExcelSheet
                    rowIndex += 2
                    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
                        .cells(rowIndex, column.Index + 1) = column.HeaderText
                    Next
                    .Range(.Cells(rowIndex, 1), .Cells(rowIndex, DataGridView1.Columns.Count)).Font.Bold = True
                    rowIndex += 1
                    For i = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                        .cells(rowIndex, 1) = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("ItemCode").Value
                        For J = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                            If IsNumeric(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(J).Value) Then
                                .cells(rowIndex, J + 1).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
                                .cells(rowIndex, J + 1) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(J).Value
                            Else
                                .cells(rowIndex, J + 1) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(J).Value
                            End If
                            'You can test also by index for example : if J = indexofTotalColumn then
                            If DataGridView1.Columns(J).Name = "Total" Then
                                total += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(J).Value
                                indexTotal = J
                            End If
                        Next
                        rowIndex += 1
                        .Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.AutoFit()
                        .Columns("L").ColumnWidth = 0
                        .cells(5).Locked = False
                    Next
                    .Protect("fakepwd")


                End With


                ExcelApp.Visible = True
                ExcelSheet = Nothing
                ExcelBook = Nothing
                ExcelApp = Nothing
            End If
        Catch
        End Try
```

TYSM for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Locked` property of the cell to false, where J+1 is the desired column number.

For example to unlock column 5 :

```
For J = 1 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
If J=5 then
 .cells(rowIndex, J + 1).Locked=False
End if
 If IsNumeric(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(J).Value) Then
..........
```

In the code, once you are done populating data in sheet, protect the sheet

```
Next
.Protect ("fakepwd")
End With
```

Comment: Sir does this code will locked all columns except the yellow one? because for me it looks that J will be the only locked. Please shed me some light

Comment: sir... lol :) plz remove that. :) By default, all the cells are locked in excel sheet, so when you set it false for any cell and protect the sheet, you can edit that cell and rest of the cells will be un-editable. So `J` or whatever cell you set as false for locked  will be the only editable cell or cells. Just add it to your code and test. simple.

Comment: i tried your code sir and all columns are locked but supposed to be the yellow one will not be locked plks the edited post

Comment: sir ... i didn't understand you. can you rephrase?

Comment: What I mean sir is i tried your code and after i test it all of the cells are locked. My target here is locked the all columns except the columns "Order Qty" or with the yellow color. You can see the post i pasted the new code

Comment: ` .cells(5).Locked = False` will only unlock the cell `E1`. add the unlock code after the line where cells loop. see the edited answer. delete this line from your code ` .cells(5).Locked = False`

Comment: TYSM sir, Its already approved and sir one more is it possible to prevent a cell or column to be prevent from any string? I mean only numbers will be inputted the column

Comment: yes. look into datavalidation. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-f809371b-214e-4e45-b4b0-f010b1159828

Comment: TYSM sir :) for help